# React - Components to create and update db model, inheritance or composition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React. My use case implies a create page for a database model and an update page. I have a lot of duplicate code in those and coming from regular OOP design I would create a base class for it and let the two component inherit.

However, after reading several forums, I saw that you should mostly prefer composition over inheritance with React. Would that also apply in this use case? It seems odd to model this via composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think composition also applies to your use case. From what I understand you will have almost the same page for `update` and `create`, all your model files will be the same in both cases. So you can make a reusable component, some form. And use it in `create` and `update` page, just perform the right action for each of them.